# SQL MATCH phrase difficulty

Tags: php, sql, match

So I'm doing a random MATCH AGAINST for phrases/words.
I've got these phrases in the database

WHERE
            MATCH (keywords.keyword) AGAINST ('$keyword*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
how are you?
how will you?
When the search/$keyword is identical to one of the phrases - the other one still gets selected from time to time.
An identical match should be that, identical right?
Is it because the search is matching a single word and not the entire string/phrase?
Can't see how else to solve this.
Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: if searching like this is going to be important consider  Sphinx or Lucene or one of the others designed for this

Comment: I've heard of Sphinx. I'll check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about stop words and minimum word length.  These are key parameters that control what "words" get indexed.

The stop word list consists of common words, such as "are", that are ignored in the index (and in searching).

The minimum word length is the minimum length of a word.  It is 3 (`innodb_ft_min_token_size` = 3) or 4 (`ft_min_word_len` = 4).

Both of these can be overridden, but you have to rebuild the index.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes sense.